# Comparing normalized and partially normalized quadratic form of normal variables

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, normalization

Suppose $X=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)' \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is the variance-covariance matrix of dimension $n\times n$ for the vector $X$.

Let $a=X'\Omega^{-1}X$. It is known that $a\sim \chi^{2}(n)$.

If we also let $b=X'\Sigma^{-1}X$, where $\Sigma=\textrm{diag}(\textrm{var} (X_1),\ldots,\textrm{var}(X_n))$. Then can we say something about distribution of $a$ and $b$? For instance, does one dominate the other in the first or second order?

Comment: This is relevant:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442472/sum-of-squares-of-dependent-gaussian-random-variables/442916#442916

Comment: You mean joint distribution of $(a,b)$ or distributions of $a$ and $b$ separately?

Comment: @mpiktas separately.